# Laravel checkbox old input

Tags: checkbox, laravel5

Вывожу ответы на вопросы с помощью пагинации (1 вопрос на странице).
Я хочу чтобы при переходе со страницу на страницу оставался старый ввод чекбокса. Посмотрел все вопросы на стаке по этой теме, но ни чего не помогло.

```
       @foreach ($quest->answer as $answer)
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox ml-5 my-1">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[{{ $answer->id }}]"  value="{{ $answer->id }}" 
@if (is_array(old('checkbox')) && in_array($answer->id, array_keys(old('checkbox')))) checked @endif>
            <label class="custom-control-label h6-responsive" for="checkbox-answer{{ $answer->id }}">{{ $answer->answer }}</label>
          </div>
            @endforeach
    {{ $questions->links() }}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как вы учитываете варианты ответов: какой-то js, или на стороне сервера расчеты ведутся?

Comment: Я еще не написал это, но планирую что весь вывод пагинации будет в одной форме и по кнопке будет отправляться на сервер для проверки и записи, ну а потом редирект назад.

Comment: Добавил скриншот для наглядности. Перед отправкой на сервер пользователь может перемещаться между вопросами и соответственно при перемещении должны сохраняться выбранные чекбоксы. Как это сделать пока не могу сообразить... Пытался выводить весь масив на страницу и уже в jquery резать на страницы, но тоже не вышло(

Comment: Самое простое, что приходит в голову - это разместить вместо пагинации кучу submit `<input type="submit" name="question" value="ТУТ НОМЕР ВОПРОСА">`

Comment: Необходимо предварительно на стороне сервере организовать логику расчетов и определить связи моделей User Question Answer. Если таковая имеется,то лучше к вопросу приложить.

Comment: Сделал с помощью jQuery плагина twbsPagination. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разметку не сохранял. Имя checkbox специально задал другое `other_checkbox`, что бы вам нагляднее было. Checkbox вот так выводится, в вашем случае, если это массив значений

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="other_checkbox[888]" value="1"
        @if(old('other_checkbox.888', 0) == 1)
            checked
        @endif
    /> Ответ 888</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="other_checkbox[999]" value="1"
        @if(old('other_checkbox.999', 0) == 1)
            checked
        @endif
    /> Ответ 999</label>
```

Вот так выполняется проверка (валидация)

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'other_checkbox' => 'sometimes|required|array',
    'other_checkbox.*' => 'required|accepted'
]);
```

Comment: Это все прекрасно, но проблема в том что это сработает только когда нажму  на кнопку завершить (одна кнопка на все вопросы (например 10 страничек пагинации)), а нужно чтобы при переходе со странички 1 на страничке 2 сохранился выбранный чекбокс на страничке 1.  Чтобы стало понятнее скажу что это система тестирования пользователя. Или может  есть плагин для реализации тестирования?

Comment: Наверняка уже есть готовые пакеты, смотрите на гитхабе.